# Javascript when button is clicked is being colored while the other buttons lose their color

Tags: javascript

I have an rate app box,
I want the user to rate the app from 1-5 by clicking one of five buttons. 
The button that was clicked should have color, all the others none.
 So if he clicked first on 3 and then 2, when clicking on 2 the color from the 3 button will be removed so only the last button was clicked (in this case 2) will have a color.
I DID manage to do it using button array, but i know for sure there is shorter way that isnt involved button array, only by code inside the function.

html:

```
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" class="img-star">
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <h1>How did we do?</h1>
      <p id="content-paragraph"> 
      Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated 
      to help us improve our offering!
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button value = 1  class="choose " id="btn-one" onclick="paintBtn(this)">1</button>
      <button value = 2 class="choose" id="btn-two" onclick="paintBtn(this)">2</button>
      <button value = 3 class="choose" id="btn-three" onclick="paintBtn(this)">3</button>
      <button value = 4 class="choose" id="btn-four" onclick="paintBtn(this)">4</button>
      <button value = 5 class="choose" id="btn-five" onclick="paintBtn(this)">5</button>
    </div>
    <form action="thankYou.html">
      <button id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body
```

> 

js:

```
const buttonOne = document.getElementById("btn-one")
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById("btn-two")
const buttonThree = document.getElementById("btn-three")
const buttonFour = document.getElementById("btn-four")
const buttonFive = document.getElementById("btn-five")

const buttonsArr = [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour, buttonFive]

function paintBtn(button) {
    buttonsArr.map(btn => btn.classList.remove("btn-clicked"))
   button.classList.add("btn-clicked")
  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The shorter way of doing and not having to pass every button inside an array would be to do a `document.querySelectorAll(".choose")` and with that way you would be able to access the NodeList of matching elements to your class.

You can examine it just like any array. If the array is empty (that is, its length property is 0), then no matches would be found.

Otherwise, you can use standard array notation to access the contents of the list. You can use any common looping statement, such as a `forEach` statement.

It works just fine as in the attached example.

```js
function paintBtn(newClickedButton) {
  // clear styling from buttons
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".choose");
  buttons.forEach(function(button){
     button.classList.remove("btn-clicked");
   });
  newClickedButton.classList.add("btn-clicked");
}
```

```css
.btn-clicked{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="./images/icon-star.svg" alt="" class="img-star">
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <h1>How did we do?</h1>
      <p id="content-paragraph"> 
      Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated 
      to help us improve our offering!
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button value = 1  class=" choose" id="btn-one" onclick="paintBtn(this)">1</button>
      <button value = 2 class=" choose" id="btn-two" onclick="paintBtn(this)">2</button>
      <button value = 3 class=" choose" id="btn-three" onclick="paintBtn(this)">3</button>
      <button value = 4 class=" choose" id="btn-four" onclick="paintBtn(this)">4</button>
      <button value = 5 class=" choose" id="btn-five" onclick="paintBtn(this)">5</button>
    </div>
    <form action="thankYou.html">
      <button id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use onclick functionallaity to solve this problem okay

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead `document.getElementsByClassName` to search for the button that is currently clicked instead of searching and traversing through all of the buttons:

```
function paintBtn(newClickedButton) {
  const clickedButtonClassName = "btn-clicked";
  const clickedButton = document.getElementsByClassName(clickedButtonClassName)[0];
  clickedButton.remove(clickedButtonClassName);
  newClickedButton.classList.add(clickedButtonClassName);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried it and also your code, didt work but thanks

Comment: Woops, I made a mistake, it should be ```document.getElementsByClassName(clickedButtonClassName)[0];```. Does this work?